# How can I know which button was clicked?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form with a "Submit" and a "Cancel" buttons. In `hook_submit()`, how do I know which button was clicked?

Comment: Are you talking of `hook_submit()` or a form submission handler? A form submission handler is not the implementation of `hook_submit()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must use the `triggering_element` from the `$form_state['triggering_element']`.

Best practice is to define a `#name` attribute for your button, so you can have this value in the `triggering_element`.

For example:

```
$form['delete'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Delete'),
  '#name' => 'delete',
);
```

If you don't define this attribute `triggering_element` will hold the button's `#value` (the text that user can read), but this is discouraged as other modules may change this value or be changed by the localization).

You may use `$form_state['clicked_button']` too, but this is **deprecated**.

You can read more info at the [drupal_build_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) function documentation page.

Comment: As of Drupal 8.8(maybe earlier) you use $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#value'] (or #name or whatever triggering_element array index you want). Accessing $form_state properties directly as an array element reference will now throw an error.

Answer (score 7):

`$form_state['clicked_button']['#value']` will tell you which button was clicked on the form.

Comment: `$form_state['clicked_button']['#value']` :)

Comment: I like to add, if you have required field(s) on your form, and they are not filled in, then you Drupal will thrown a form validation error (form_submit is called after form_validate). You need to do something like this http://devengineering.com/best-practices/drupal/cancellation-required-validation-drupal-6

Comment: That's a good point!

Comment: While "clicked_button" still works, it has been deprecated in D7 and the recommendation is to use "triggering_element" instead. I remember there were some #ajax bugs (I think) that only affected code that used "clicked_button", so that's one more reason to use "triggering_element". And after all, it's just a different key in $form_state.

Comment: Note that, when disabling validation functions, Drupal 7 has a new FAPI element "#limit_validation_errors" that allows you to use as many (or as few) validation functions as you want. Insert a blank array() to disable all validation without the D6 workaround.

Comment: While this approach works, it is deprecated and prone to problems. See tunic's answer for the correct Drupal 7 way to do this.

Comment: As a note: this shows you the submit value -- the text on the button. If all of your buttons say "Save" it won't help.  However $form_state['clicked_button']['#id'] tells you the exact button you clicked. But as others have said, $form_state['triggering_element'] is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

## **UPDATE 2016 Drupal 8**

For those still trying to figure out how to access the triggered event here is the Drupal 8 solution.

`$form_state->getTriggeringElement()`

This returns the array of the triggering submit element. If you add a markup called `#name` then you would access it with the following way.

`$button_clicked = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name']`

The reason behind this change is that `FormStateInterface` is now a `readOnly` file in which only classes that extend `FormStateInterface` can access the variables. So you have to use accessor methods like `getTriggeringElement()` in order to access the variable.

Comment: I have an update for Drupal 8.4.4 in 2018: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/256112/1441

Answer (score 3):

Name the buttons with the `#name` attribute, like this:

```
$form['delete'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Delete'),
    '#name' => 'delete',
);
```

and then use:

```
$values = $form_state['input'];
if (isset($values['delete'])) // 'delete' button was pressed.
```

Comment: So for a form with two submit button like this : 
$form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#name' => 'submit-1',
            '#value' => t('Submit1'),
        );
        $form['submit2'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#name' => 'submit-2',
            '#value' => t('Submit2'),
        );

We just have to check $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'] in the submitForm() function ?

Answer (score 2):

Compare these values in `$form_state` I have been doing in Drupal 6 and would be same in Drupal7

```
if($form_state['values']['ok'] == $form_state]['clicked_button']['#value']){
    //Process if OK is pressed
}else if($form_state['values']['cancel'] == $form_state]['clicked_button']['#value']) {
    //Process if Cancel is pressed
}
```

Comment: If I remember correct Drupal 6 $form_state]['X'] is now $form_state['X'] in Drupal 7

Comment: Why do you need to compare these two values?

Comment: If form contains multiple submit buttons. This comparison will help to differ which button used to submit the form in a single submit handler. $form_state['clicked_button']['#value'] = t('Yes') will result different values on multilingual setup.

Comment: A single comparison is best to avoid all language comparisons in multilingual setup. :)

Comment: @iStryker I am not sure what you mean with your first comment.

Comment: $form_state did some weird things in Drupal 6 and earlier.  To pull a value you did $value = form_state]['value'].   Drupal 7 got rid of this I think.  Or maybe I have this wrong, and it was found in Drupal 5, but got rid of in Drupal 6.  ANYWAYS, there is a syntax error in Shoaib answer

Comment: `$value = form_state]['value']` is this even valid php?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8.4.4 `$form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];` gives you the value of `op`. When you look for that key in the form state's values array, you get the `#value` key of the button form element-- in other words, the string that the end users sees on the button on the page.

I don't know if `$form_state->getValues()['op']` is universal for all forms, but I'm hard-coding it in my module's form.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 8.6.7**

Create button something like below.

```
$form['my_button'] = [
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Custom Button'),
    '#name' => t('customButton'),
    '#weight' => 0,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['populate-bib-button', 'btn', 'btn-primary'],
    ],
  ];
```

In your submit function get button name like below code.

```
$input = $form_state->getUserInput();
print $input['_triggering_element_name']; // customButton
```

Comparison can be done like

```
if ($input['_triggering_element_name'] == 'customButton') {
  // Do something.
}
```

#Drupal8

Comment: Don't translate the #name, or if you do you must translate it in the if too.