# Evaluating whether a button was clicked with php code in Rules

Tags: nodes, rules

Using the [Publish Button](https://drupal.org/project/publish_button) module, I added Publish/Unpublish buttons to some of my nodes. I want the site to perform an action every time an admin clicks "Publish" after editing a node.

I followed some instructions from [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/how-can-i-know-which-button-was-clicked), but my php code always evaluates to false. Since $form_state['clicked_button']['#value'] is deprecated, I tried another approach. I added a #name attribute ('publish') to the button (line 103 of publish_button.module) and wrote this function inside the Rules interface (execute custom php code):

```
function button_check() {
$values = $form_state['input'];
  if (isset($values['publish']) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is the code from the module file (line 103):

```
    function publish_button_render_publish_button() {
  $publish_button = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#value' => t('Publish'),
    '#weight' => '30',
    '#name' => 'publish',
    // Add the submit handler.
    '#submit' => array('_publish_button_publish_node'),
  );
  return $publish_button;
}
```

I am aware that I might be making some serious beginner's mistakes here, but I am new to Drupal and php.

Comment: Hi, why not just use rules > https://groups.drupal.org/node/97454#comment-940263? Or, do you a specific trigger when the publish button is used rather than say marking the publish checkbox and clicking save?

Comment: Your suggestion is good and I can solve my problem that way, but I would like to implement this button as a custom button with a specific purpose - to at once publish the node and perform some other actions. I would like to know why the above code isn't working and what the proper way would be. If I don't find a solution, I will certainly do as you suggested.

Comment: Ok, can you clarify what you mean by "wrote this function inside the Rules interface"? As execute custom php code?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Is that all of the code you're using the execute custom php? If so, then nothing is calling your function. Even if you do call your function, you're not passing the $form_state variable...I'm not even sure $form_state is going to be available. What trigger or reaction are using in your rule? I'm thinking you may need to take a completely different approach.

Comment: I recommend writing a custom rule trigger to integrate Publish Button with rules directly. I'd follow one of these articles to integrate them and submit it as a feature request to Publish Button. http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/rules-creating-and-customizing-events/ or http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token

Comment: This is the code inside the "condition" part in Rules. The condition to be evaluated. The trigger is "After updating a node of type x". After that comes the action. I knew that I was doing something seriously wrong, I need at least some hints.

Comment: Thank you. The first link isn't working, though.

Comment: the link > http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/rules-creating-and-customizing-events/